# Do these limitation exist for Lex?

Tags: amazon-web-services, chatbot, amazon-lex

I am new to using Amazon Lex engine and I have few questions to better understand its limitation since I couldn't find anything related in the docs:

1. Do amazon's Lex support composite entities? If so reference or
   example.
2. Do amazon's Lex support taking any value that the user gives, for example
   if I'm taking the users feedback I want to let him say anything even if it's a troll or meaningless answer.
3. Can Amazon Lex take in lists, for example, if I want to give
   multiple names having 1 simple prompt for the name won't do it I
   want a list prompt is that possible?

**EDIT:** 1-There are 2 names slot types `AMAZON.DE_FIRST_NAME` `AMAZON.GB_FIRST_NAME`, one that supports names most commonly known in great britain the other for german, i need the composite entity feature to combine these 2 slot types into one entity.

2- I simply want to take the user's input exactly as it is, it may be `sbfhbf` or `my feedback is none of your business` or whatever it might be.

3-Let's say i asked the names of the people on the dinner table in a restaurant i want the names of everyone , currently i'm using `amazon.gb_first_name` and i'm only able to take in 1 name and actually print it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Do amazon's Lex support composite entities?
   Answer: No
2. Do amazon's Lex support taking any value that the user gives?
   Answer: No
3. Can Amazon Lex take in lists?
   Answer: YES (As of June 2021, Lex now accepts [multi-valued slots](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lexv2/latest/dg/multi-valued-slots.html))

EDIT: Updated answer as suggested by user Rodrigo

Comment: Thank you for the answer, is their any official lex documentation that suggests so as i pretty much looked all over and didn't find that included anywhere even in the limitations section http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/gl-limits.html#gl-limits-model-building .

Comment: its not a limitation, its a functionality that Lex does not provide at the moment. all the functionalities provided by Lex are documented. there may be workarounds available, try to post your requirement, and problem, maybel people will be able to help you.

Comment: I edited my question to showcase what i'm trying to do , requirements and problems.

Comment: As of June 2021, Lex now accepts [multi-valued slots](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lexv2/latest/dg/multi-valued-slots.html), so "yes" to question #3.